# why doesn't htop display the same process start time than ps

Tags: linux, process, htop

Ubuntu 16.0.4.5, htop 2.0.1 and 2.2.0 compiled from source.

Showing the STARTTIME column in `htop`, displays `Jan25` but `ps -o lstart` displays `Sat Dec 15 20:58:46 2018`

By looking at the `pid` it seems that `ps's` output is incorrect, but `htop's` not.